# Keyboard hides tab bar

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, keyboard, tabbar

I have a view controller with a tab bar at the bottom, and a text field at the top.
I want to make the keyboard appears up to the tab bar when I tap the text field.
Else I can't access the tab bar while the text field is first responder

Comment: It's kind of normal that the keyboard appear on top of the tab bar. Try to use this library to help you manage your keyboard and text fields: https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQKeyboardManager

Comment: Thannks ! I'll try it